# How do I get a color in LESS without the #?

Tags: less

I have a service that returns a lovely svg gradient for use in IE, and I'm trying to use this with a less mixin like this --

```
.Gradient(@start, @stop) {
  background-image: url("/imageService/GradientSvg?startColor=@{start}&endColor=@{stop}");
}
```

The problem is, these colors begin with #, which truncates the url that the server receives.

I need a way of getting the color without the #.  I don't mind if its RGB values, or the hex values without the prefix.

I had tried url encoding the # by using a javascript call like this

```
  background-image: url(`"/shop/image/GradientSvg?startColor=@{start}&endColor=@{stop}".replace("#","%23")`);
```

And I think it would have worked except that my less processing is happening on the server, and it can't evaluate the javascript when done this way.

Any ideas how I can extract the color in a way that will work in the url?  I'm flexible in how the service works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with.  I use a color function to apply a tiny bit of transparency.  This ensures that I always end up with an RGBA color, not one beginning with a #.

```
.Gradient(@start, @stop) {
  @startRgb: fadeout(@start,1%);
  @stopRgb: fadeout(@stop,1%);
  background-image: url("/ImageService/GradientSvg?startColor=@{startRgb}&endColor=@{stopRgb}");
```

the url now always contains the rgba notation for the color, and my service is happy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass the colors in as strings instead of colors?  So when you call your mixin, it'd just look like this?:

```
.Gradient("000000", "FFFFFF");
```

If you need those colors defined as colors elsewhere, you could try using backticks to parse the value out in Javascript.  So it'd be something like:

```
@noHash: ~`"@{start}".substring(1)`;
```

I'm not sure how those color values look when you pass them into JS, though.  They might be a color object, and require conversion to a string.  I guess I'll have to try that some time...

Comment: Thanks.  The script thing would have worked.  In my example I just replaced # with %23 so that it wouldn't muck up rgba colors which don't begin with a #.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to have two variables for each colour, you can use the `color` function to convert a string:

```
@myColorString: "FFD700";
@myColor: color("#@{myColorString}");
```

Use whichever variable you need.

```
color: @myColor;
background-image: url("/colors?color=@{myColorString}");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a general use gradient mixin.  I want the flexibility to be able to pass in any type of color, even an RGBA.